# Sort the words and letters in Java

Tags: java, sorting, tokenize

The code below counts how many times the words and letters appeared in the string. How do I sort the output from highest to lowest? The output should be like:

```
the - 2
quick - 1 
brown - 1 
fox - 1
t - 2
h - 2
e - 2
b - 1
```

My code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Tokenizer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = 0;
        int tokenCount;
        int i = 0;
        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> letterCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        String message = "The Quick brown fox the";

        StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(message);

        tokenCount = string.countTokens();
        System.out.println("Number of tokens = " + tokenCount);
        while (string.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String word = string.nextToken().toLowerCase();
            Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
            Integer lettercount = letterCount.get(word);

            if (count == null) {
                // this means the word was encountered the first time
                wordCount.put(word, 1);
            } else {
                // word was already encountered we need to increment the count
                wordCount.put(word, count + 1);
            }
        }
        for (String words : wordCount.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Word : " + words + " has count :" + wordCount.get(words));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
            char c = message.charAt(i);
            if (c != ' ') {
                int value = letterCount.getOrDefault((int) c, 0);
                letterCount.put((int) c, value + 1);
            }
        }

        for (int key : letterCount.keySet()) {
            System.out.println((char) key + ": " + letterCount.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `Map<String, Integer>`; I'd suggest something along the lines of another `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>` which is populated by inserting keys that are sorted by value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to sort the Map by it's value (i.e., count). Here are some [general solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java).

Specifically for your case, a simple solution might be:

1. Use a `TreeSet<Integer>` to save all possible values of counts in the `HashMap`.
2. Iterate the `TreeSet`from high to low.
3. Inside the iteration mentioned in 2., use a loop to output all word-count pairs with count equals to current iterated count.

Please see if this may help.

Answer (score 1):

just use the concept  of the list and add all your data into list and then use sort method for it

Comment: This is not a decent answer.  Please take the time to explain to the OP how they should approach this in detail.  It's always good to write some code which demonstrates your answer.